# Setting up a web server using go

Tags: go

I'm not expecting to get the code written for me, I just want a nudge in the right direction.

I have a task to make a web server that listens to port 8080, on this server i shall present data that is readable to humans. The person accessing this server will get to these paths using /1, /2, /3 etc. The data that is to be presented is to be gathered from 5 different APIs, and all of these are to return data in JSON format.

Also all of the paths are to be rendered to the person using Go templates.

How would one go about doing this?
I might sound like i'm giving out homework, but I really new to this and need some help.

Comment: This should be a good and extensive intro for you: [The Go Programming Language: Writing Web Applications](https://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/)

Answer (score 1):

I found the following very helpful when learning to do the same:

- https://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/

  A nice tutorial on creating a simple html based web app with the [net/http](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/) package. The package can be used to gather information from the apis you use as well as send your response json. It introduces html templates but the process is largely unchanged for json templates.
- https://medium.com/@IndianGuru/understanding-go-s-template-package-c5307758fab0

  An overview of Go's templating engine.
- https://blog.golang.org/json-and-go

  A blog post about using go to encode (marshal) and decode (unmarshal) data in json.

Answer (score 1):

You will have lots of resources from the answers. I would like to give some simple code you can test if it's fitting your needs:

Have a simple folder structure like this:

```
ProjectName
├── main.go
└── templates
    └── index.html
```

Inside `main.go` we create a http server listening on port 8080. Here is the entire code commented:

`main.go`

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

// User information of a GitHub user. This is the
// structure of the JSON data you are rendering so you
// customize or make other structs that are inline with
// the API responses for the data you are displaying
type User struct {
    Name     string `json:"name"`
    Company  string `json:"company"`
    Location string `json:"location"`
    Email    string `json:"email"`
}

func main() {
    templates := template.Must(template.ParseFiles("templates/index.html"))

    // The endpoint
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        user, err := getGithubUser("musale")
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        }
        if err := templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.html", user); err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        }
    })

    // Start the server on 8080
    fmt.Println(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}

// One of your API endpoints
func getGithubUser(username string) (User, error) {
    var resp *http.Response
    var err error
    var user User
    // The endpoint
    const githubUserAPI = "https://api.github.com/users/"

    // Get the required data in json
    if resp, err = http.Get(githubUserAPI + username); err != nil {
        return user, err
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    var body []byte
    if body, err = ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body); err != nil {
        return user, err
    }

    // Unmarshal the response into the struct
    if err = json.Unmarshal(body, &user); err != nil {
        return user, err
    }

    return user, nil
}
```

And then in the `index.html` just use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Github User</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
    <p>Name: {{.Name}}</p>
    <p>Company: {{.Company}}</p>
    <p>Location: {{.Location}}</p>
    <p>Email: {{.Email}}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Most of the resources address the code snippet and with some more tinkering, you will be able to pass params into the URL, render the data according to the route etc. I hope this gives you an idea on how it's easy to solve your problem. Good luck!