# Linking my HTML to Go Lang

Tags: go

I'm trying to show my result set and Variables from .Go Lang to an HTML Page.

[Assuming this tree view as my workspace.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0NpM.png)
    **Home.HTML**

```
 <div id="Golang"><p>My Name is : <i>{{.myName}}</i></p></div>
    <div id="Golang"><p>Some Random Database Test: <br>{{.Country}} {{.City}} </p></div>
```

**db.Go**

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

type world struct {
    Country sql.NullString `json:"country"`
    State   sql.NullString `json:"state"`
    City    sql.NullString `json:"city"`
    Abbr    string         `json:"abbriviation"`
    id      int            `json:"id"`
    CCode   int            `json:"CountryCode"`
}

func main() {

    name := "Sam"

    dsn := "root:1234@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/script"
    // Open database
    fmt.Println("We're going to connect a MySql Db")
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", dsn)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer db.Close()

    fmt.Println("Successfully connected to Mysql Db")

    results, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM CountryDb WHERE Country =?", "India")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    for results.Next() {
        var tag world
        err = results.Scan(&tag.Abbr, &tag.Country, &tag.CCode, &tag.State, &tag.City)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error()) 
        }
        log.Printf(tag.Abbr, tag.Country, tag.CCode, tag.State, tag.City)
    }

}
```

Now how can i show values from my Go program to HTML Tags.
This is my first go program and I'm not much aware of this language. I go through some online tutorials but the way they are written is not very helpful.
so any help on this would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: This is your first app? congrat, start with the documentation : https://golang.org/doc/code.html https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html    https://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/ you obviously didn't read any of it.

Comment: I wrote an answer for the creation of a go webserver https://stackoverflow.com/a/49923337/4444629 I hope it sheds some light for you regarding the use of templates.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't compile. Look at why that is.

Comment: @mpm Thanks for the tutorials.

Comment: @musale This is something i was looking for. thanks mate.

Comment: @MichaelHampton it does compile. the problem is (or can say unaware)  about go templates (which I'm learning now).
anyway thanks for the comment.

Comment: @Sam you're welcome :)

Comment: @Sam Er, the code in this question **does not compile** because you omitted relevant parts of it. But yes, you need to learn about html/template (which is based on text/template).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a template file:

**tpl.gohtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>The Number from Go Code is: {{.}}</h1> 
</body>
</html>
```

And your **main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "text/template"
)

var tpl *template.Template

func init() {
    tpl = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("tpl.gohtml"))
}

func main() {
    err := tpl.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "tpl.gohtml", 42)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
}
```

In the init function you parse the template file created above. If you have many of them you can use `ParseGlob(pattern string) (*Template, error)` But for this example you can parse the template by name.
After we done this we execute the template with the name `tpl.gohtml` and print it out on the `Stdout` and handle errors.

Now you can run the code with `go run main.go` and you get the following output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>The meaning of life: 42</h1>
</body>
```

You can see that the last argument of the `ExecuteTemplate()` Function is the data you passed to your template. You can also use slices, maps or self created complex data types to the template and iterate over it.

**main.go with a slice**

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "text/template"
)

var tpl *template.Template

func init() {
    tpl = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("tpl.gohtml"))
}

func main() {

    sages := []string{"This", "is", "a", "string", "slice"}

    err := tpl.Execute(os.Stdout, sages)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
}
```

and the corresponding template could look like this

**tpl.gohtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Slice Data</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    {{range $index, $name := .}}
    <li>{{$index}} - {{$name}}</li>
    {{end}}
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

This would give you the following output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Slice Data</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>

    <li>0 - This</li>

    <li>1 - is</li>

    <li>2 - a</li>

    <li>3 - string</li>

    <li>4 - slice</li>

</ul>
</body>
```

If you want to create the html files with this code just use `go run main.go > outputfilename.html`

[Golang Web Dev Github. Sources of a Udemy course](https://github.com/GoesToEleven/golang-web-dev)

[Go Templates](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/)